# Cadastrar no banco um array separado

Tags: php, typescript

Tenho uma **API** em **PHP** e um **app** feito com **ionic** 3.

Estou recebendo do app uma string dessa forma "`200,300,40`" e outra a mesma coisa "`polimento,pintura,lavagem`".

Gostaria de saber como faço para cadastrar cada numero e nome desse separado no `insert` linha por linha ?

Existem outros dados alem desse números como data etc.., mas ele vem apenas um registro simples sem virgula tipo: `23/04/2016` não teria problema em repeti-los nas linha do banco". Então queria isso ficasse linha por linha.Tipo:

```
nome_servico     valor_servico    data_servico   id_usuario   .......
polimento        200              23/04/2016
pintura          400              23/04/2016
lavagem          40               23/04/2016
```

---

```
$count= 0;
$max = count($varnome);
while($count <= $max){
$sql = "insert into pedido(nome_servico,valor_servico,id_usuario,total_servico,data_servico,id_empresa,n_pedido)values('".$varnome[$count]."','".$varvalor[$count]."','".$id_usuario[$count]."','".$total_servico[$count]."','".$data_atual[$count]."','".$id_empresa[$count]."','".$comp_ped[$count]."')";
$count++;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque um exemplo de código para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

***Use o loop para gerar a string,***

```
$count= 0;
$max = count($varnome);
while($count < $max){
  $values .="'".$varnome[$count]."', '".$varvalor[$count]."', '".$id_usuario."', '".$total_servico."', '".$data_atual."', '".$id_empresa."', '".$comp_ped."'),(";  
  $count++;
}
```

***e depois do loop faça o insert***

```
//retira os 3 caracteres indesejáveis no final
$values= substr($values,0,-3); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO pedido(nome_servico,valor_servico,id_usuario,total_servico,data_servico,id_empresa,n_pedido) VALUES ($values)";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query ->execute();
```

**Não obstante, acredito que o resultado esperado seja:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> "o unico caso que eu faço exceção é quando são muitos values. Ai eu faço 2 loops. Um externo, e outro interno que junta até N valores. (de 50 em 50, por exemplo) mas isso pra evitar queries muito grandes que extrapolem o tamanho máximo do pacote de dados da conexão." dica do @Bacco.

O mais difícil foi entender a pergunta do jeito que foi publicada antes das edições! [image: suando.gif] - `Nome: valor data` davam a impressão de que fossem nomes de colunas as quais não constavam na declaração `insert`

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você pode dá um explode na virgula e transforma em  uma array, ai  você coloca em um loop e pega os valores pelo index

```
<?php
    $nome = $stringNome.explode(",");
    $code = $stringCodigo.explode(",");
    $count = 0; //contador para pegar o index
    $max = count($nome); // numero maximo de registros

    while($count <= $max){
       mysql("sua query aqui VALUES('".$nome[count]."','".$code[count]."')");
       $count++;
    }

?>
```

Comment: não compreendi o seu comentario